# OpenCV 3.0 xfeatures2d not found

Tags: opencv, sift, opencv3.0, surf

I am using MAC Yosemite. I installed the OpenCV 3.0 with extra modules as follows:

> "opencv_contrib" in build directory
>   accessed build directory from terminal:
>   cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH= opencv_contrib/modules/ /Users/junaidyounas/documents/opencv-3.0.0 
>   make install

and also with `sudo make install`
But still I am not able to find "**xfeatures2d.hpp**" which means the extra module is not installed properly.

I followed the [official installation process](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/), that notifies successfully installed with 1 error.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the code broke here:

> [ 91%] Built target opencv_test_java /Users/junaidyounas/documents/opencv-3.0.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc‌​/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:171:52: error: no member named 'isVector' in 'cv::_InputArray'

Comment: I followed the installation process [link] (https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/) it notifies successfully installed with 1 error

Comment: I noticed that the code broke here: [ 91%] Built target opencv_test_java
/Users/junaidyounas/documents/opencv-3.0.0/build/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:171:52: error: 
      no member named 'isVector' in 'cv::_InputArray'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by making following changes:

1. The problem I experienced was in opencv_contrib/module/ximgproc, I deleted the module
2. Editing the command:*cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=opencv_contrib/modules/ ./
3. It worked for me but without **ximgproc**

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Using the 3.0.0-rc1 version (apr. 24) solved the problem for me.